# Shared Preference Value updated with installation

Tags: android, preferences, shared

Im trying to make a currency converter, and so I get the values from the internet and if the user turns the internet off the values are being saved in the shared preferences so that the user can go on using the converter without the internet.
 
The problem is first installation. How can I make it work in the way that shared preferences from the last usage install themselves within the application. Let me give you an example:

1) I  get the current rates, save them using shared preferences.
2) I uninstall my app
3) Install my app again
4) Rates in my shared preferences are the ones from point 1.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that your Prefs are remain after you deleted and installed your application again? Looks like you should add

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

in your Manifest in the `<application>` block, because I guess your Prefs are stored in your Google Drive :)
From official documentation:

> Whether to allow the application to participate in the backup and restore infrastructure. If this attribute is set to false, no backup or restore of the application will ever be performed, even by a full-system backup that would otherwise cause all application data to be saved via adb. The default value of this attribute is true.